# MS Teams Adaptive Card mentions break on refresh

Tags: node.js, botframework, microsoft-teams, adaptive-cards

I'm trying to manually trigger refresh for an Adaptive Card but the mention breaks after the card refreshes. I added the refresh proprty to the card with 'userIds'. The initial render of the card shows mentions correctly.

[Adaptive Card](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Inp2G.png)

Card JSON:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
  "version": "1.5",
  "type": "AdaptiveCard",
  "body": [
    {
      "type": "TextBlock",
      "text": "<at>User1</at>, <at>User2</at>"
    }
  ],
  "msteams": {
    "entities": [
      {
        "type": "mention",
        "text": "<at>User1</at>",
        "mentioned": {
          "id": "8:orgid:<EntraId>",
          "name": "User1"
          "aadObjectId": <EntraId>
        }
      },
      {
        "type": "mention",
        "text": "<at>User2</at>",
        "mentioned": {
          "id": "8:orgid:<EntraId>",
          "name": "User2"
          "aadObjectId": <EntraId>
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I'm using NodeJS and Adaptive Card npm package v2.10.0